# How to directly access JSON data as an object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table where one of the columns has the data type "json". The column is called `payment_data` and inside of it I have a JSON object:

`{"success":true,"status":0,"resposta":"OK","referencia":"44304425","entidade":"5555"}`

I found an example online that I could call directly in Laravel, using this example:

`{{ $order['payment_data->entidade']}}`

But it doesn't work so I guess it is not right. Is there a helper available to get the information directly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override cast variable in your model:

```
protected $casts = [
 'payment_data' => 'object'
 ];
```

Then you can use like this:

```
{{ $order->payment_data->entidade }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) on your model which would allow you to access the JSON data as an array.

For example, you can add the following to your your model class:

```
protected $casts = [
    'payment_data' => 'array',
];
```

Then you should be able to access values inside the JSON value like this: `$order->payment_data['entidade']`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$order = new Order::find( 1 );

$json_data = json_decode( $order->payment_data );

echo $json_data->entidade;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a json like this

```
{"success":true,"status":0,"resposta":"OK","referencia":"44304425","entidade":"5555"}
```

you can do like this to access the **values**

```
$json = {"success":true,"status":0,"resposta":"OK","referencia":"44304425","entidade":"5555"}
```

the you can access the values like this

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json['entidade'];
```

I hope it helps some one,this how i solved my problem.